# Html5Converter (PHP)

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to output the html content of a xml-Textfield inside a service. Tried to use Html5-Converter. The Converter is loaded in my service. I tried following:

```
php

$body = $content->getFieldValue('body')->xml;
$html = $html5Converter->convert($body);
```

I get an exception: [LogicException]Rendering a fragment can only be done when handling a request
Any ideas about this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is probably not running inside `request` scope (see more about this in [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html)). For example you may use service that depends on `request` service inside console command.

Check dependencies of services, you use or try to emulate scope by putting empty `Request` in container and then call `\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface::enterScope('request')`